# I want that particular stock ,That last two record of avg price is < currentprice in order by Scrip_Id,Date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want that particular stock ,That last two record of avg price is < currentprice in order by  Scrip_Id,Date.

My sql table structure is below
[image]

Comment: What queries have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should bring back any stocks which, on the last 2 records (based on date, I assume there is one row per scrip_id and date), had an average price less than the current price (on each row).

```
select e.exchange, e.scrip_id
  from entry_master e
 where e.date >=
       (select max(y.date)
          from entry_master y
         where y.scrip_id = e.scrip_id
           and y.date < (select max(x.date)
                           from entry_master x
                          where x.scrip_id = e.scrip_id))
   and e.avg < e.currentprice
 group by e.exchange, e.scrip_id
having count(*) > 1
```

If you need more than just the name of each applicable stock and you want all of their details from the table, you can use the below:

```
with sub as
 (select e.scrip_id, min(e.date) as min_date, max(e.date) as max_date
    from entry_master e
   where e.date >=
         (select max(y.date)
            from entry_master y
           where y.scrip_id = e.scrip_id
             and y.date < (select max(x.date)
                             from entry_master x
                            where x.scrip_id = e.scrip_id))
     and e.avg < e.currentprice
   group by e.scrip_id
  having count(*) > 1)
select e.*
  from entry_master e
  join sub s
    on e.scrip_id = s.scrip_id
   and (e.date = s.min_date or e.date = s.max_date)
 order by e.scrip_id, e.date
```

Comment: @PranaySoni No problem, please mark it as the answer if you are all set.